# Visual Studio 2019 has errors after cleaning the VS extensions folder in the Temp directory, cannot even install VS installer

Tags: visual-studio

I was cleaning up useless files from my disk when I came across the dreaded Temp folder. It had all the extensions used by the Visual Studio installer to add Xamarin functionality to Visual Studio (as I was testing it), as well as probably some older ones (e.g. C++). I searched to find out if deleting them was safe or not and [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/50gb-vsix-files/718903) a Microsoft person said it was OK to remove the .vsix files in that drectory but **not anywhere else**. So, I proceeded to delete them.

Fast forward a couple days, I opened a solution I wanted to work on and I was [presented with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3VP1.png).

The stack trace (as given from VS itself) is this:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)
   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode,IntPtr errorInfo)
   at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.Shared.Common.StartProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo,EventHandler onExited,EventHandler onDisposed)
   at async Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubControllerClient.StartAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at async Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.LaunchOrFindControllerAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at async Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.GetLocationServiceAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at async Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.Shared.ServiceHubRetry.ExecuteAsync[TReturnType](<Unknown Parameters>)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at async Microsoft.ServiceHub.Utility.Shared.ServiceHubRetry.ExecuteAsync[TReturnType](<Unknown Parameters>)
   at async Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.GetThisAsRemoteServiceBrokerAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at async Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.<Reset>b__54_0(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at async Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.AsyncLazy`1.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<GetValueAsync>b__0[T](<Unknown Parameters>)
   at async Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.ThreadingTools.WithCancellationSlow[T](<Unknown Parameters>)
   at async Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.GetPipeAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at async Microsoft.ServiceHub.Client.HubClient.RequestServiceAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Remote.ServiceHubRemoteHostClient.RequestServiceAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Telemetry.WindowsErrorReporting.WatsonReport.GetClrWatsonExceptionInfo(Exception exceptionObject)
```

I can't even open VS Installer to repair it, let alone re-installing the installer itself. [VS Installer error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bc60b.png)

VS Installer error info (taken directly from Event Viewer):

```
Error Information
AppInsightsEvent Name = vs/setup/bootstrapper/error
          Description = Generic Error
     TelemetrySession = 'c62216e8-62fa-4ff0-878d-52901aed9dc6' Started = True OptIn=True IsInitialized = True Cloned = False
      WatsonEventType = VisualStudioNonFatalErrors2
             UTC time = 2021-06-04T21:18:15

 Exception:
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperException
 Unable to launch the installer. Error: A device attached to the system is not functioning
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.StartProcess(String exeDir, String exeName, String args)
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.ExecuteCore()
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.<>c__DisplayClass24_0.<Execute>b__0(Object s)

     Inner Exception:
     System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
     A device attached to the system is not functioning
     System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
     System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
     Microsoft.VisualStudio.Setup.Bootstrapper.Bootstrapper.StartProcess(String exeDir, String exeName, String args)
WerReportAddDump PID=15648 vs_setup_bootstrapper WerDumpTypeMiniDump
```

I tried uninstalling both from the Programs and Features menu, but it instead told me that it may have already been uninstalled, though the folders are still present. I have also tried [Microsoft's InstallCleanup.exe guide](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2019), but the executable is nowhere to be found.

Is there any way I can repair Visual Studio, or at least uninstall it and reinstall it?